# Remove duplicated but with priority for keep first in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a df:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 
seqA NA 10
seqA Unknown 5
seqA Cow 50
seqB NA 2
seqC NA 2
seqC Unknown 2
seqC Bird 6
seqC Cow 1
seqD Unknown 30
seqD Shark 2
```

so the idea would bee to remove duplicated COL1 value and keep only one with the lowest `COL3`BUT only take ones with `NA` or `Unknown` containt if there is no other `COL3 value < 10`

for instance for `SeqA`

I keep

```
seqA Unknown 5
```

because thise one is > 10 :

```
seqA Cow 50
```

but in
seqC I keep :

```
seqC Cow 1
```

because it is  `<10`

In the exemple the expected output would be :

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 
seqA Unknown 5
seqB NA 2
seqC Cow 1
seqD Shark 2
```

So one idea would be to first do a

```
tab=df.sort_values(by=['COL3'], ascending = True)
```

But I do not know how to integrate the priority by the fact that everything different from Unknwown or NA is a priority except it its COL3 > 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do filter then `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`

```
out = df[df.COL3.lt(10) | df.COL2.eq('Unknown')].sort_values('COL3').drop_duplicates('COL1').sort_index()
Out[47]: 
   COL1     COL2  COL3
1  seqA  Unknown     5
3  seqB      NaN     2
7  seqC      Cow     1
9  seqD    Shark     2
```